# Problem with insert into PostGIS view table via QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql-view

I use a PostgreSQL 9.5.14 (PostGIS) and QGIS 2.18.7.

The problem is that when I try to add a new object to the View via a QGIS, the following error occurs:

> ERROR:  column "geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type integer
>       LINE 1: INSERT INTO testtr VALUES (NEW.objectid, NEW.num_pdr, NEW.ge...
>                                                        ^
>       HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
>       QUERY:  INSERT INTO testtr VALUES (NEW.objectid, NEW.num_pdr, NEW.geom)
>       CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function testtr_view_dml() line 4 at SQL statement

But update and delete triggers work properly. 
I think problem is in the trigger function for insert.

My query:

At first i create a table in pgAdmin with next query

```
-- Table: public.testtr

-- DROP TABLE public.testtr;

CREATE TABLE public.testtr
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('testtr_id_seq'::regclass),
  geom geometry(MultiPointZ,100000),
  num_pdr integer,
  CONSTRAINT testtr_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.testtr
OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.testtr TO postgres;
```

Next I create a view for this table with query

```
-- View: public.testtr_view

-- DROP VIEW public.testtr_view;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.testtr_view AS 
 SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY testtr.*) AS objectid,
    testtr.num_pdr,
    testtr.geom
FROM testtr;

ALTER TABLE public.testtr_view
OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.testtr_view TO postgres;

-- Trigger: testtr_view_dml_trig on public.testtr_view

-- DROP TRIGGER testtr_view_dml_trig ON public.testtr_view;

CREATE TRIGGER testtr_view_dml_trig
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON public.testtr_view
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.testtr_view_dml();
```

I need this view to be editable in QGIS so I create a trigger fuction

```
-- Function: public.testtr_view_dml()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.testtr_view_dml();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testtr_view_dml()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO testtr VALUES (NEW.objectid, NEW.num_pdr, NEW.geom);
        RETURN NEW;

        ELSEIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        UPDATE testtr SET geom = NEW.geom WHERE id=OLD.objectid;
        RETURN NEW;

      END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.testtr_view_dml()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

AND at last the trigger

```
-- Trigger: testtr_view_dml_trig on public.testtr_view

-- DROP TRIGGER testtr_view_dml_trig ON public.testtr_view;

CREATE TRIGGER testtr_view_dml_trig
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON public.testtr_view
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.testtr_view_dml();
```

Comment: the error is actually quite self-explanatory, no? in your trigger function you insert the columns in the wrong order. btw. `DELETE` doesn't do anything in your setup.

Comment: @ThingumaBob You are right. Thank you. I changed it to `(NEW.objectid, NEW.geom, NEW.num_pdr)`, but it caused a new error **ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 01040000A0A0860100010000000101000080E7FF885C43DFD340E269667A2A57..., 66).**

Comment: `id` is defined as a self-incrementing sequence; you're not supposed to insert values in it. since `NEW.objectid` holds no value and is thus `null`, it violates the constraint. remove the `NEW.objectid` from the `INSERT` column list.

Comment: @ThingumaBob 
I tried to write `INSERT INTO testtr VALUES (nextval('testtr_id_seq'::regclass), NEW.geom, NEW.num_pdr);` and it works. Thank you to show the problem.